# Обратиться к директории, зная лишь начало её названия

Tags: c#

Есть какая-то папка

В ней куча подпапок "DIR-1 (hello)", "DIR-2 (hi)", "DIR-100500 (ave)"

Я знаю что все подпапки начинаются с "DIR-n", где n - иднтификатор. Далее в названии подпапки может быть абсолютно что угодно. 
Мне известен n. Как получить полное название этой папки?

Есть вариант решения:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath(/*родительская папка*/)))
    if (file.IndexOf("DIR-" + id.ToString()) != -1) 
        /* то file - путь + полное название*/
```

Есть более быстрый способ? Папок может быть очень много.

Comment: У `Directory.GetDirectories` есть перегрузка принимающая `searchPattern`

Comment: Не заметил, спасибо.

Comment: @Андрей: Почему не как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь перегрузкой [`Directory.GetDirectories()`, принимающей строку для поиска](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6ff71z1w(v=vs.110).aspx), это, как минимум, более оптимально:

```
var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(..., $"DIR-{id} *");
if (dirs.Length > 0)
{
    // Папка найдена
    var dir = dirs[0];
    ...
}
else
{
    // Папка не найдена
    ...
}
```